# logcat: couldn't open output file '/storage/logFile.txt': Permission denied

Tags: android, adb, logcat

How to get permission to save logcat history as file?

Tried: ./adb logcat -f /storage/logFile.txt
logFile.txt already exist឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵
឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵ ឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵឵

Comment: There is no permission on the whole world that would allow for such a path.

Comment: Why? it can only write to SD card?

Comment: No to many storage locations.

Comment: Where I can save it?

Comment: In most public directories on external storage for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a PC (or Mac) and an Android device connected via adb (e.g. USB) to the PC

If you execute `adb logcat` on your PC then the command you execute is `adb` hence if you redirect standout to a file you need to use a path on your PC not on your phone.

If you want to save the logcat output on your phone you need to open a shell, execute logcat there and then redirect the output to a file:

```
adb shell "logcat -f /storage/logFile.txt"
```